# How to set backcolor for docking windows at runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms, docking

I created a Docking windows program in csharp i want to change the color of that tabs after exe is getting executed.because those tabs will be added at run time.i can able to change the TabText but i cant able to set the values

```
          dockContainer1.ActiveDocument.DockHandler.TabText = "Welcome"

            |Tab1|Welcome|Tab3|
            |                     |
            |                     |
            |                     |
            |                     |
            |_____________________|
```

I want to change the Background color at runtime...how to do it .. ?

Comment: Tabs are drawn using the user's favorite theme.  You'll need to use DrawMode + DrawItem to override that.

Comment: sir how to do that. can u please guide me

Comment: yes i want to change like that..even i made code for Mdicontroller and Mdiclient..but color is not getting set –

Comment: There's a good example in the MSDN article for TabControl.DrawItem.

Answer (score 0):

a little confused, but do you mean something like..

```
yourTab.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.TheColourYouWant
```

if not, please try and explain more, but this is how you change the tab backing colour, in the designed and at runtime.

Comment: yes i want to change like this..even i made code for Mdicontroller and Mdiclient..but color is not getting set

Comment: can you not use my answer then..? this is how they do it in the designer, i see no reason why it wouldn't work in a class for at runtmie.